# How to boot Any Linux Distro on an MSI GE73 8RF

Tags: debian, ubuntu, fedora, kernel, panic

I'm trying to get any Distro to even boot into a Live Session. since this isn't working i'm to0 scared to even try installing one. Hoever every distro i tried Gives a "Kernel panic" or a freeze during boot

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (kernal 4.15) - Kernel Panic > https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQyml.jpg 
Fedora 28        (kernel 4.17) - Kernel Panic
SlackEX 14.2     (Kernel 4.14) - Freeze black screen
Debian 9.4       (Kernel 4.9 ) - Freeze       > https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xVFQ.jpg

Relevant Specs?:
Intel I7 8750H (Intel UHD 630 Graphics)
Nvidia 1070 GTX 
NVME M.2 SSD Toshiba 256 GB WD 1TB 
USB31(Gen2 10gbps)

Comment: Are you booting with UEFI mode? Can you disable secure boot and boot from legacy/BIOS method?

Comment: Disabling Secure boot and switching to legacy (CMOS) in the bios.Was the first thing i did. It's what alowed me to even try booting

Comment: Have you tried blacklisting the nvidia driver? Try that, if not try to see if you can disable the nvidia card in BIOS and only use the Intel graphics until you can install the proprietary drivers etc.

Comment: Yes i tried adding Kernel boot parameters nomodeset and modprob.blacklist=nouveau. The bios does not allow me to disable dGPU or iGPU

Comment: The HM370 Chipset, processor, and graphics card should all be supported, however this appears to be a very new laptop. Linux does not have the best support of bleeding edge hardware. How did you create the flash drive? I recommend using `dd` if at all possible, as I have never had issues using `dd` creating a live boot or Linux installer. Also have you tried Arch Linux? If the latest Arch-based Linux installer cannot boot I would suggest that you contact the developers of the Operating System you wish to use and the manufacturer of your laptop and see what support there could be provided.

Comment: Any update on this?  Did you update the BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install Debian testing (buster, 10) on the GE73 Raider 8RF laptop on second ssd, but i'm still having some issues that i don't know how to fix, yet.

What I did was install using netinstall, and in the first boot after installation I start in maintainance mode. after the root password:

1. restart NetworkManager (systemctl restart NetworkManager)
2. install vim (optional, i don't like nano editor)
3. vim/etc/apt/sources.list  adding repos "contrib" and "non-free" after main
4. apt update
5. apt install firmware-linux-nonfree firmware-iwlwifi
6. reboot

after booting, I get to GDM3 login screen. but i can't solve the problems after that

- Using wayland (default) got total freeze. mouse cursor stop moving, ctrl+alt+f1 to f6 doesn't change to console..
- Using Xorg (X11) mouse keep moving, but can't change to console.
- Not using gdm login screen and change to console. log to root and after a few minutes, can't keep writing, but can change to other terminal to keep trying to do something

i'll try adding firmware-realtek and other firmware that i found that is missing from installation. i'll pin this post to update if I manage to pass through those errors.

Update: managed to fix freeze after gdm3 login screen. I took the suggestion of blacklisting nouveau on boot (modprobe.blaclist=nouveau) and voilá. gnome3 working fluid af. so I will blacklist permanent nouveau.

img showing debian working: **[my laptop with debian buster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4UNY.jpg)**

link explaining how to make nvidia work on linux : **[install nvidia drivers in gnu/linux](https://www.tecmint.com/install-nvidia-drivers-in-linux/)**